# Add keys conditionally in Scala to a Map[String,String]?

Tags: scala, dictionary, collections

I want to add keys as shown below:

```
val x = false
  val y = Map[String,String](
    "name" -> "AB",
    if(x) "placement"->"pc" else null
  )
  println(y)
```

Note that its an immutable map, this works when x is true but throws runtime error when x is false, I tried to put `else Unit` but that doesn't work as well.

Can someone point me the most elegant as well as optimized syntax to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more option is

```scala
val y = Map[String, String](
  Seq("name" -> "AB") ++
    (if (x) Seq("placement" -> "pc") else Seq()): _*
)
```

or

```scala
val y = (Seq("name" -> "AB") ++
  (if (x) Seq("placement" -> "pc") else Seq())).toMap
```

or

```scala
val y = (Seq("name" -> "AB") ++
  Option.when(x)("placement" -> "pc").toSeq).toMap
```

This is not so shorter but maybe slightly less confusing than `if (...) Map(...) else List(...)`.

Comment: thank you so much Mr Scala Wizard! :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorted it like this:

```
val x = true
  val y = Map[String,String](
    "name" -> "AB"
  ) ++ (if(x) Map[String,String]("place"->"pc") else Nil)
```

still wondering if this is good or something better should be used.

Comment: `Map[String,String]("place"->"pc")` has type `immutable.Map[String, String]`. `Nil` has type `List[Nothing]`. So `if(x) Map[String,String]("place"->"pc") else Nil` has type `immutable.Iterable[(String, String)]` and `Map` can accept this in `.++(...)`. I guess it's ok.